# Python - edit Powerpoint slide contents in a presentation that already exists

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-office, powerpoint-2010

I'm using Python 2.7.2 and Office 2010 on Windows 7. I have a Powerpoint file that has links to other documents in a directory. I would like to use Python to loop through the shape captions, find matching names in the directory, and create a hyperlink in the Powerpoint file. As long as I can read those shape captions I can do the rest.

I managed to do this and at least open the Powerpoint file:

```
import win32com.client

Presentation = Application.Presentations.Open("c:\\path\\to\\stnd4.pptx")
```

I have found a number of ways to add slides that don't already exist and add shapes or captions, but I can't seem to find any way to edit *existing* slides. This lets me add a slide:

```
Base = Presentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)
```

But anything that tries to open or edit an existing slide just fails:

```
Base = Presentation.Slides.Open(1)
Base = Presentation.Slides.Edit(1)
```

I also tried

```
help(Presentation)
```

but I just get generic `win32com` info, nothing on Powerpoint slides. Googling didn't turn up much, either. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

There's no concept of "opening" or "editing" a slide in the PowerPoint object model.  Instead, you get a reference to a slide (which I suspect your "Base = Presentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)" line accomplishes).

PowerPoint has a hierarchical object model:  Presentation contains Slides, Slides contain Shapes, Shapes have various properties that you can modify via their properties and methods.

I don't use Python or know how fully it can communicate with PPT, but:

Your BASE object (a slide, remember) probably has a Shapes collection.  Iterate through the Shapes collection and for each shape try something like this:

```
If the shape's .HasTextFrame property is true then
   If the shape's .TextFrame.HasText property is true then
      The shape's .TextFrame.TextRange.Text property will return the text in the shape.
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Understanding the hierarchy of PP slides will help me poke around. I might be able to loop through them and update the links.

Comment: Each Slide also has a Hyperlinks collection that you can loop through.  You'll be looking for the .Address and .SubAddress property of each hyperlink.  I suspect that no matter what language you're using to automate PPT, you'll do well to fire up PPT, Alt+F11 to get into the VBA IDE, then do a bit of coding there, or at least press F2 to view the Object Browser.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. More and more it seems I have to learn VBA. I'd prefer to do this in Python since I already know it, but it seems like maybe VBA is the way to handle this.

Comment: It's not so much that you have to learn VBA, but if you already have PowerPoint, you've got VBA, and it gives you a fair amount of help in understanding the object model ... how PowerPoint "thinks".